# Connecting phone calls with twilio

Tags: twilio

This is more of a general quest ok but when using Twilio dial in a twiML to connect the caller to another number, can you disconnect Twilio after they are connected or will it just keep connected and increase the call time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds like you are asking whether, when you direct a phone call to a TwiML app with something like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial><Number>OTHER_PHONE_NUMBER</Dial>
</Response>
```

that you want to disconnect from Twilio once the call is connected to the number?

If that's the case, then the answer is no, I'm afraid. Once a call comes into Twilio, it is being controlled and routed by the Twilio system and you will incur costs by the minute. Whilst this call continues to live you will still be able to affect it via the REST API using its call SID.

Let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That's exactly what I wanted to know